# Forcing Remote Desktop to listen on an adapter on Server Core

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp, nic, windows-server-core

I appear to have the problem described here:

"After cloning and syspreping [...] VMs running Windows [...], I was not able to connect to the cloned servers by Remote Desktop.
After troubleshooting the steps below, I noticed the the RDP-TCP listener was not listening on a network adapter. (I am certain it occurred while cloning /VMTools update)"

[enter link description here](http://danielruiz.org/2012/09/05/remote-desktop-not-available-after-cloning-a-windows-server-2008-r2-virtual-machine/)

Alas, I cannot use the proposed solution:

"Open Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration[...]"

The VM in question is running Server Core.

Is there a way to force Remote Desktop to listen on an adapter using the command line interface? Disabling and enabling Remote Desktop in sconfig.exe doesn't do it.

Comment: Is this Server 2008 R2, 2012, or 2012 R2?

Comment: This is 2012 R2, but I need/want to know generally.

Answer (score 1):

I asked in a comment about your OS, but your link specifically refers to 2008 R2 so I will assume that for now.

In that case, I would recommend you open Remote Desktop Session Configuration on another machine, then right click on **RD Session Host Configuration** and choose **Connect to Remote Desktop Session Host Server** to connect to the machine running core.

Like so many things in core on 2008 R2, having a machine with a GUI is probably the easiest way to achieve this.

If that doesn't work, or you don't have access to another machine with the tool, check this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp
```

I noticed that the the `LanAdapter` value changed when I changed the setting you're interested in. I only have 1 adapter on my server. When the setting was set to **All network adapters configured with this protocol** the registry value was `0`. When I changed the setting to explicitly use the one adapter I have, the value changed to `1`.

So perhaps changing this to `0` will allow it to work after when clone the VM, after which you could lock it down so to speak if you feel it's necessary.

Comment: I tried that setting as per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555382 but no combination actually worked.